# how to get complete hierarchy ids of given id in mysql into comma separated string

Tags: mysql, string, hierarchy

i have the following table i want to get complete hierachy of a particuler id:

---

id,parent_id

---

1,null

---

2,1

---

4,1

---

5,2

---

6,2

---

7,5

---

for id=2
i want to get "5,6,7" as output

---

reason for above output is 5,6 are childs of 2 and 7 is child of 5

---

it should work for any number of levels in a hierarchy